# AppWidgetProvider with dagger2

Tags: android, android-widget, dagger-2

I try to use Dagger2 with [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html).
But my beans are never inject by dagger.

I start from sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample

My AppModule:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    MyDb provideDb(Application app) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(app, MyDb.class,"my.db")
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }
}
```

My WeatherModule

```
@Module
public class WeatherModule {

    @Singleton @Provides
    public OpenWeatherMapService provideOpenWeatherMapService() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(new LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
                .build()
                .create(OpenWeatherMapService.class);
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    public WeatherDao provideWeatherDao(MyDb db) {
        return db.weatherDao();
    }
}
```

My Widget Dagger component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, WeatherModule.class})
public interface WeatherWidgetComponent {
    void inject(Context context);
}
```

My application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    private WeatherWidgetComponent weatherWidgetComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        
        AppInjector.init(this);

        weatherWidgetComponent = DaggerWeatherWidgetComponent.builder()
                .build();
    }

    public WeatherWidgetComponent getWeatherWidgetComponent() {
        return weatherWidgetComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

My AppWidgetProvider

```
public class WeatherAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Inject
    WeatherDao weatherDao;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        inject(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        inject(context);

        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateUI(appWidgetManager, context, widgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
        super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
        inject(context);
        updateUI(appWidgetManager, context, appWidgetId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        inject(context);
    }

    private void inject(Context context){
        Timber.d("inject");
        if(weatherDao ==null) {
            Timber.d("null so try to inject");
            ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getWeatherWidgetComponent().inject(context);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, Context context, int appWidgetId){
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.weather_widget);

        if(weatherDao ==null){
            Timber.d("weatherDao null");
        }
    }
}
```

In logcat I always have:

> 11-14 18:41:43.494  3812  3812 D WeatherAppWidgetProvide: inject
>
> 11-14 18:41:43.495  3812  3812 D WeatherAppWidgetProvide: null so try to inject
>
> 11-14 18:41:43.198  3812  3812 D WeatherAppWidgetProvide: weatherDao null

Comment: You have to specify concrete class for field injection, not just base class (Context)

Answer (score 2):

As Gabor pointed out in the comments, you have to specify a concrete class for field injection.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, WeatherModule.class})
public interface WeatherWidgetComponent {
    void inject(Context context);
}
```

Injecting `Context` will not do anything, because `Context` does not have any `@Inject` annotated fields. The generated code will basically try to inject a context and do nothing.

If you were to replace the call to `void inject(Context context)` with `void inject(WeatherAppWidgetProvider provider)` Dagger will generate code to properly inject `WeatherAppWidgetProvider` and calling `.inject(this)` will actually do something.

Comment: Thanks it works. Is it "clean" to create component in my AppWidgetProvider ? because I'll have multiple AppWidgetProviders and I prefer to keep my application class light. I want to create a BaseAppWidgetProviders to create  component and inject instance of my AppWidgetProviders.